# Writing text to flat file using spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have batch program which will take data from data base and place in a flat file using JdbcCursorItemReader and FlatFileItemWriter. However now I want to append some simple hard coded text at the beginning of file.
Please help how to do it?

Comment: did you check the spring batch documentation e.g. http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#addingAFooterRecord ? there is a headercallback as well

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a class implementing FlatFileFooterCallback interface or just use default implementation SummaryFooterCallback class.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileFooterCallback.html